# I think my PiFM just broke my Raspberry Pi

Tags: pifm

I followed the PiFm [instructions](https://www.instructables.com/id/Raspberry-Pi-Radio-Transmitter/) to broadcast a .wav file on 87.5 MHz. I connected my antenna to GPIO 4, but nothing happened. Then I unplugged & tried again, but got the same result. I think I may have touched more than one pin at once with the antenna at some point. I don't know when it stopped working, but when I tried to stop the broadcast found that ssh had stopped working.

I unplugged the pi (I know you should do `poweroff` but I couldn't), and plugged it back in. The ACT light does not light up but the power light stays on. I have changed the storage device, the power supply but nothing works. Did I fry my pi permanently? Is there anything I can do? Would a warranty cover this? I'm not sure where the Pi was purchased as it was a gift.

Comment: `I think I may have touched mote than one pin at once` If that's the case then it most likely wasn't pifm, but you that broke the Pi... And I hope using pifm is legal in your part of the world. BTW: did you try running a freshly downloaded Raspbian Stretch on a fresh SD card?

Comment: Yeah... I didn't realize that touching the two pins would fry the pi. I did use a fresh sd card with a fresh OS install. An d the same with some USB drives. I hope I didn't break the pi, I was just about to buy a microphone to try a new project.

Comment: RPI GPIO pins are sensitive. Check out the pinout satellite boards, they are made so you don't brick the RPI. Not much you can do thats worth your time

Comment: @colinrosati Shoot, I wish there was a warning on the instructions that it had the possibility of bricking my pi. I guess I'll order a new one